# MySqli php Make Table only view-able to SESSION user or those at his level

Tags: php, mysqli

beginner here.. this one is a bit complicated.
I created 2 tables, 1 table is for data a user can submit, the other table is for user names passwords and user levels.

ive created user log in levels, 
each user can submit a record to the database.
I want to make it so the Active user can only see what he has submitted AND what other users at his level and below have submitted.
ex.
level 4 user can see all submitted by level 1 2 3 and 4
level 3 can see all submitted by level 1 2 3
etc

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `employeeinfo` WHERE CONCAT(`posted`) LIKE '%".$_SESSION['sess_user']."%' OR (`id`) LIKE '29'";
```

The OR id is just a current place holder.

But i guess i want IF (sess user)Mike = (level)3
Then Show 'Posted by' Sess user (which i already did) OR show all where 'Posted By' (which is a name field) is level 3, 2, 1 (in the level field)

Comment: Which table is `employeeInfo`? Is it the table for data a user can submit, or the one with the user names and levels?

Comment: If it's the user info table, why does it have a `posted` column?

Comment: Well, my 1 table which im calling "employeeinfo" has 'id' 'name' 'surname' 'Comments' and 'Posted by' ... I made it so when a user submits into this tbale, it automatically put Current sess user into 'Posted by' .......... Now my other table ill call 'credentials' is just Username Password and UserLvl

Comment: it would be best if you showed your table schema in the question.

Comment: Table1 = id, name, surname, comments, posted by.... Table2= Username, Pass, Userlvl

Comment: It would be best if you showed your table schema in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join with the `credentials` table twice. Once to get the level of the logged in user, and then to get the names of all the users with the same or lower level.

```
$query = "
    SELECT e.*
    FROM employeeinfo AS e
    JOIN credentials AS c1 ON e.posted_by = c1.username
    JOIN credentials AS c2 ON c1.user_level <= c2.user_level
    WHERE c2.username = '{$_SESSION['sess_user']}'";
```

Comment: interesting, though ive never seen this before... is that the full function that i would query= .... And the last line, would i make it = to current sess user?

Comment: Yes, replace `'Mike'` with the session user. Ideally, using a prepared statement, not variable substitution.

Comment: @Barner doesnt seem to be working for me. do i have to declare e as a variable? currently i have... $query = "SELECT e.*
FROM employeeinfo AS e
JOIN users AS c1 ON e.posted_by = c1.username
JOIN users AS c2 ON c1.lvl <= c2.lvl
WHERE c2.username = 'Mike'";

Comment: Actually. it may be working, need to do more testing! thank you sir!

Comment: @barner i believe its working. Awesome awesome stuff, You're the man! inspiring stuff.

Comment: ...having an issue, the bottom line.. WHERE c2.username = 'John'"; ...im trying to use current sess user... i keep getting errors.... WHERE c2.username = '<?=$_SESSION['sess_user'];?>'"; .....or...  WHERE c2.username = '=$_SESSION['sess_user'];'";

Comment: any help? ... WHERE c2.username = '%".$_SESSION['sess_user']."%'";  ...Gets no errors, but also shows no results in my table

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to include the variable. But it would be better if you learned how to write prepared queries.